# Sending mail and validating an actual email?

Tags: php, email

I am sending users an activation link via php, I only have a regex in place to check if the email consists of `*@*.*` which is fine, but I would like to check if the email actually sends also.

I tried to do this with

```
if (mail(....)) {
     // success
} else {
     // error
}
```

But when I enter an email of `a@a.a` it still goes through to the success step.

How can I actually check if it is a correct email in php, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

1. validate the email address preoperly with

   ```
    if (filter_var($email_a, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        echo "VALID";
    }
   ```
2. the email server will return true on accepting the email it does not know if it will get to the user the only way to do this , and i'm sure you have seen it, is to get the recipient to click on a link in the email that sends them back to your site, then you know its valid\used address.

Answer (score 2):

From the PHP docs

> bool **mail**( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )
>
> Returns TRUE if the mail was successfully accepted for delivery, FALSE
>   otherwise.
>
> It is important to note that just because the mail was accepted for
>   delivery, it does NOT mean the mail will actually reach the intended
>   destination.

Just because an email address is formatted properly does not mean that there is an actual mailbox at that location. There is no way in PHP to "check" if a email address exists/is active. That is the entire purpose of activation links, to verify that someone is checking that email address.

Comment: cgwebprojects I'm sorry but you are wrong. What I posted above is correct. You are now asking a COMPLETELY different question

" I only have a regex in place to check if the email consists of *@*.* which is fine, but I would like to check if the email actually sends also."

You asked only for is it sent or not. You never asked to validate the email. Of course @Dagon is right with checking for a valid email but you asked for "but I would like to check if the email actually sends also"

Comment: I disagree, all the major online email services, some of which use php  will tell you that the email address is not an actual email when trying to send.

Comment: I am asking the same question as above, how do I validate an actual email, my method is obviously wrong but to say php cannot do it is just plain silly!

Comment: I said "There is no way in PHP to "check" if a email address exists/is active" That statement is 100% correct

Comment: @cgwebprojects what are these 'online email services' that you speak of? having been writing email delivery software for the last 3 years I would love to know.

Answer (score 0):

+1 for filter_var().  Use it instead of a simple regexp.  Even the most complex regexp can't get every possible way of putting together an [RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.4.1) compliant address.  Your attempt to come up with something is pretty much guaranteed to fail.

But you didn't ask about address format verification, you asked about checking to see that the mail was sent.  The whole purpose of an activation link is to validate the email address.  If you clean up unvalidated accounts on a regular basis, it doesn't matter whether the email address is structured correctly.  By sending a link, you're doing a full-circuit test that bypasses any possible format misinterpretations that filter_var() might have.